# CSS conflict with ipboard skin / breadcrumb

Tags: css, web, breadcrumbs

Got a problem with my template, for whatever reason my breadcrumbs are overlapping on my menu elements as displayed here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw67i.jpg

I've tried adjusting the z-index with no luck. Wondering if there is anything I can do to solve it.

for a live example: http://aonexus.com

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting z-index Should help unless there are some flash elements, which require different methods. Make sure that your `z-index` style really gets applied to element. If your `z-index` property gets overrided with other styles, try applying it with `!important`

```
z-index: 999!important;
```

If even that doesn't help, let me know, then further research should be done.

UPD: For bottom panel this fix works:

```
#footer_utilities
{
  z-index: 2;
}

#secondary_navigation
{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

It puts footer containing your floating menu over breadcrumbs.

Comment: Works great for the top, however still having the same issues with the bottom.

Comment: `content: " ";
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
border-left: 25px solid #a68e6d;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
left: 100%;
z-index: 2;`

Comment: Still can't realize, why it happens such, but happens because of using :after pseudo-element. You can repair bottom side by setting z-index of #secondary_navigation to 1 and of #footer_utilities to 2. It will be great, if anyone explains this more deeply. I'll add these to answer.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to check the answer as correct, please)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!important` to the rule params should raise it's priority to be higher than the alternate rule.